# Strange SQL Server Fulltext match

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I stumbled upon strange fulltextindex behavior in SQL Server 2008 R2 (my word-breaker language is German).

I have this text indexed:

`[...] Java Editorerstellung in Eclipse eines Modellierungseditors(UML) mit den Eclipse Technologien [...]`

I triple-checked: The only occurrence of the term *edi* is in this short snippet of text, I can only find it as part of *Editorerstellung* und *Modellierungseditors*.

But SQL Server still has *edi* as a single word in it's fulltextindex (occurrence: 1) and therefore returns it on `ContainsTable(...)` searches. Why is it recognized as a single word?

Has anybody an explanation for this behavior? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[German Compound words](http://german.about.com/od/nounsandcases/a/German-Compound-Words.htm) require special parsing in natural language word breakers.  For example, "Editorerstellung" is parsed and stored as three separate terms, "editor", "erstellung" and "editorerstellung".  Extensive research has been done on [analyzing German compund words](http://hum.uchicago.edu/jagoldsm/Papers/GermanCompounds.pdf) and while the techniques are improving, the process is not perfect.

It is likely that the behavior you are seeing is due to heuristics being using in the word breaker.  I cannot re-produce your issue using the above snippet and the Sql Server 2012 word breaker, so either Microsoft's improvement in the German word-breaker between Sql Server 2008 R2 and Sql Server 2012 solved the problem or some text you didn't include is the source of "edi" in the full-text index.

You can use sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document() to see what terms are in the index.  Using a binary search pattern, you should be able to narrow it down to the specific text that is generating the "edi" term.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
Unfortunately I can still repro the issue in SQL Server 2012. I triple-checked, the only occurrence of "edi" is in the two words "Editorerstellung" und "Modellierungseditor". I think you're right with the word-breaker being the culprit, though. Thanks again.